# Python Falls Into If but Return Not Working

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm just trying to do a simple [hackerrrank question](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/jumping-on-the-clouds/problem). The code I've come up with prints out the answer but doesn't return it. I'm not sure why.

```
def myjump(c,j):
    if len(c) <= 1:
        print("answer: ",j)
        return j
    elif len(c) > 2:
        if c[2] == 0:
            c = c[2:]
        else:
            c = c[1:]
    else:
        c = c[1:]

    j += 1
    myjump(c,j)

    return "Test"

def jumpingOnClouds(c):
    if len(c) <= 1:
        return 0

    res = myjump(c,0)
    print("return: ",res)
    return res

result = jumpingOnClouds([0,0,1,0,0,1,0])
```

The output:

```
('answer: ', 4)
('return: ', 'Test')
```

I don't understand why the code seems to fall into the "if len(c) <= 1:" block and print the number but doesn't hit that return?

Comment: Probably the question should explain what the code is supposed to do, and/or link to the Hackerrank assignment.

Comment: I probably didn't need a recursive solution but I understand thanks to tripleee's comment. Adding `return myjump(c,j)` works

Answer (score 0):

You have a recursive function; the recursive call doesn't `return myjump(c, j)` so you're breaking the chain (if this was supposed to be recursive at all - maybe the function calling itself is a mistake?)